In odata V4 filter empty array
Url:odata/Machines?$expand=item
Output is like:
[
{
"id": 2,
"item": [
{
"id": 9,
"prod_order_id": 9,
},
]
},
{
"id": 1,
"item": []
},
]
In my odata filter I want to show data those machine.item array ain't empty.
Results should be:
[
{
"id": 2,
"item": [
{
"id": 9,
"prod_order_id": 9,
},
]
}
]

I already solve it by  adding                                                                        '/odata/Machines?$expand=item&$item/any(a:a/id ge 0)'  Hopefully that one helpful for others

Or you can omit those properties by customing the serializer. You can find more details at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/extension-omit-null-value-properties-in-asp-net-core-odata/
